# Enable save button on change of input box

Tags: javascript, html, breeze

I am breeze entity manager to check if there are changes made to entity. So i declare observable

```
isSomeChanged = ko.observable()
```

Then i tie value like this

```
 isSomeChanged(datacontext.hasChanges());
```

Html is

```
 <button data-bind="click: SaveData, enable: isSomeChanged() "> Save</button>
```

So now if i changed something in my page then it enables or disables button. But if i type something in input then button is enabled only when i tab out and not as soon as i typed.

How can i enable save button as soon as something is typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your isSomeChanged observable is updated when the breeze EntityManager's hasChanges property changes:

```
isSomeChanged = ko.observable();

// update the isSomeChanged observable when the hasChangesChanged event fires.
entityManager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(
    function(changeArgs) {
        isSomeChanged(changeArgs.hasChanges);
    });
```

Ensure your input's value binding has a corresponding [valueUpdate](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) parameter set to "input".  This will cause each change to the input is written to the entity property immediately instead of when the input loses focus.

```
<input data-bind="value: entity.FirstName, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
```

---

Also, your button's enable binding can be expressed like this (no need for the parens):

```
<button data-bind="click: SaveData, enable: isSomeChanged">Save</button>
```

Comment: just had to use valueupdate binding and it worked. Didnt used entitymanager.haschangeschanged... thanks